# Logistic regression for every column of a data frame

Tags: r, glm

I am trying to run a logistic regression on multiple dependent variables, 'traits',  which are columns in a data frame, against a single independent variable, 'score'. I'm trying to do this as either one line of code or in a loop - but not succeeding at it!

For just doing columns 4 to 10, I've tried:

```
glm_output <- glm(data.matrix(myData[,4:10]) ~ myData$Sscore, na.action=na.exclude, family=binomial(link= "logit"))
```

I get the error message: "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  for the 'binomial' family, y must be a vector of 0 and 1's
or a 2 column matrix where col 1 is no. successes and col 2 is no. failures". My columns are factors, coded as 1 and 2's and it will happily do them individually. So I'm not sure why it doesn't like it.

I've also tried:

```
`for(i in names(myData))
{       
fit <- glm(myData[,i] ~ myData$score, data=myData, na.action=na.exclude) 
 }
```

However this gives me one coefficient rather than one for every column of the data frame.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It the formula y goes first, eg. `myData$Sscore ~ data.matrix(myData[,4:10])`. Could you provide myData?

Comment: Sscore is the independent variables, so is right as he wrote.

Comment: Do you want as a result an array with your coefficient or a list with every fit?

Comment: @adiana, my bad, of course you are right in this case.

Comment: @R.Mitchell, just extract what you need from `fit` inside the for loop and store it in a list or data.frame.

Comment: Thank you both. @adiana - I would prefer it as an array otherwise would be extracting from the list to make an array.

Comment: @M.D, great shout. I'm new to programming and I'm having trouble getting it to put each coefficient in a sequential row of a data frame.

Comment: @R.Mitchell Edit done, check if it works

Comment: @adiana - yes, it has worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find all the name of the independent variables to use

```
regressors<-setdiff(names(myData),"Sscore")
```

Run the regression for every independent variable

```
lapply(regressors,function(name){
glm(myData[,name] ~ myData$Sscore, na.action=na.exclude, family=binomial(link= "logit"))
})
```

If you want the coefficients in an array you can type:

```
sapply(regressors,function(name){
coef(glm(myData[,name] ~ myData$Sscore, na.action=na.exclude, family=binomial(link= "logit")))
})
```